# How to convert text or character to hex in korn shell

Tags: scripting, ksh

Does the unix korn shell provide a function to convert text or character to hex eg. hex 31 32 37 33 34 35 35 36 36 37 value of characters 1273455667 Here i have written the code to display but i don't know how to store the result in a variable

```
str=1273455667

for (( i=0; i < ${#str}; i++ ))
do
c=${str:$i:1}
if [[ $c == ' ' ]]
then
printf "[%s] %X\n" " " \'\ \'
else
printf "[%s] %X\n" "$c" \'$c\'
fi
done
```

Comment: `var=$(printf ...)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have `hexdump` (which is pretty likely), you could do something like this:

```
$ echo "Hello, world!" | hexdump -v -e '/1 "[%_c]: "' -e '/1 "%02X\n"'
[H]: 48
[e]: 65
[l]: 6C
[l]: 6C
[o]: 6F
[,]: 2C
[ ]: 20
[w]: 77
[o]: 6F
[r]: 72
[l]: 6C
[d]: 64
[!]: 21
[\n]: 0A
```

For a simple space separated hex dump into a variable:

```
$ v=$(printf %s 1273455667 | hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02X "')
$ echo "$v"
31 32 37 33 34 35 35 36 36 37
```

Comment: Hi rici thanks for reply can't i convert ascii to hex without using hexdump?

Comment: You  can use printf  but only one character at a time.

Answer (score 2):

```
str=1273455667
unset hex_values
for (( i=0; i < ${#str}; i++ )); do
  c=${str:i:1}
  hex_values+=($(printf "%X" "'$c"))
done

echo "${hex_values[*]}"
```

Note that in `ksh93`, `printf '%X\n' "'$character"` gives you the character's code point, not the hex values of the bytes that form that character in the current encoding. In that regard, it's different from `od -An -vtx1`.

For instance, in UTF-8 locales, for € (encoded as e2 82 ac in UTF-8), it would give 20ac (the unicode code point for the Euro symbol), not e2 82 ac.

You can obtain the same behaviour as in `od` if you force the locale to C (with `export LC_ALL=C`).

Here, we're using command substitution (`$(...)`) to retrieve the output of the command. In `ksh93`, when the command is built-in, that doesn't involve creating a pipe and forking a subshell, so it's relatively efficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
I occasionally do this to insert binary strings into an sqlite db
# Convert a string to hex using od
cat testfile   |
od -An -td1 | 
{
 print -n "x'"
 while read aline
 do    for i in $aline 
       do  print -n "%02x"
       done | read format
       printf "$format" $aline
 done 
 print "'"
} | read hexstr
echo "$hexstr"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the awk [Velour library](//github.com/svnpenn/velour):

```sh
velour -n '
do print mt_basecon(str_ord(ARGV[1]), 10, 16)
while (ARGV[1] = str_slice(ARGV[1], 2))
' 1273455667
```

Result:

```
31
32
37
33
34
35
35
36
36
37
```